# How to get an androidapp to do something at a certain time of the day

Tags: java, android, performance, timer, repeat

I would like to write my first Android app using Java and I was wondering how to schedule the app to perform a certain task, or call a method at a user-specified time of day. Also, I would like this to happen without having to keep the app constantly running in the background.

Is there a way to have the user set up a time at which the Android system wakes the app to do what it's supposed to do? Or do I have to have the app load on startup and constantly running in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called an Alarm. Have a look at [AlarmManager](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=alarmmanager&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html&ei=KR8hT9ulH-aNiAfNk9zsBA&usg=AFQjCNE1Xy99Kn5P4zGr8t2xbOOAlbSMQQ).

Comment: Thanks I guess that is all I need, how neat:) I think I will find it quiet enjoyable to code this. Thank you!